# Make memoir class \flexlabelled left justified

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir, enumitem

In Memoir class, I can `\usepackage{enumitem}`, and then make a nice description list. I tried to do the same with Memoir's built-in `flexlabelled` environment, but the labels are fully justified. MWE:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage[variant=uk]{english}
  \setmainfont{Open Sans}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Lights (enumitem)}
\begin{description}[style=multiline,leftmargin=4cm,font=\normalfont\sffamily]
  \item [SR tripod] 300W PAR56, vertically > Marjolaine
  \item [somewhere, possibly] 12V 50W or 300W PAR56 > house
\end{description}

\chapter*{Lights (flexlabelled)}
\newcommand*\sfl{\raggedright\sffamily}
\begin{flexlabelled}{sfl}{4cm}{*}{0mm}{5cm}{0mm}
  \item [SR tripod] 300W PAR56, vertically > Marjolaine
  \item [somewhere, possibly] 12V 50W or 300W PAR56 > house
\end{flexlabelled}

\end{document}
```

which makes:

[image: enumitem vs flexlabelled]

You can see the second set of labels are fully justified, and thus barely readable. I can't get those labels left justified, eg:

```
\newcommand*{\sfl}[1]{\sffamily{\raggedright{}#1}}
```

doesn't change anything.  Anyone understand what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\sfl` should have an argument (the label); `\raggedright` does nothing, because the label is typeset in a `\makebox`, use `\hfill` to force left alignment.

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setdefaultlanguage[variant=uk]{english}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Open Sans}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\newcommand*\sfl[1]{\sffamily\raggedright#1\hfill}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Lights (flexlabelled)}
\begin{flexlabelled}{sfl}{4cm}{0mm}{0mm}{4cm}{0mm}
  \item [SR tripod] \SI{300}{W} PAR56, vertically > Marjolaine
  \item [somewhere, possibly] \SI{12}{V} \SI{50}{W} or \SI{300}{W} PAR56 > house
\end{flexlabelled}

\end{document}
```

I have used a serif font for the main text just to show that the `\sffamily` declaration is only applied to the label.

[image]